# SQL Loop assigning values

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops

I am working with SQL Server 2014, and would like to write a loop to help fill in the nulls in the issuer and trader columns with values in the security column. In the sample table, I am trying to assign '030' to the issuer column in rows 1 through 4, and assign 'Billy' to the Trader column in those same rows. In rows 5 through 8, I need '062' in the Issuer column and 'Jimmy' in the Trader column. The only way to safely identify what an issuer is and what a trader is, would be to say that a security and trader will always have a CAVC value of NULL. Also, Issuer and Trader always have a 1 to 1 relationship, and when a new group of securities comes up (like starting with row 5) the issuer always precedes the security. I would like to put this code into my ETL, which runs every day.

Thanks in advance for any help!

[sample table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qarxi.png)

Comment: It's best to include all relevant information, code, and images directly in your question so people do not need to click on links to external sites. Also, this ensures that over time your question doesn't loose important context through dead links. Many potential answerers won't bother clicking on links, and just skip your question.

Comment: Side note. 99% sure you don't need a loop for this

Comment: It would better if you provide sample and desired output data to get the proper answer soon and try to elaborate all the conditions that you want.